# Melhores práticas ao trabalhar com Multithread

Tags: c#, multithreading

O pseudo-código abaixo está seguindo as boas práticas para um código assíncrono? Ele deveria:

1. Iniciar sincronamente diversas tasks;
2. Após iniciar as tasks, aguardar pelo término de todas elas para efetuar um pós processamento;

Esta é a melhor forma de executar um processamento paralelo em grande escala para depois obter seu resultado? Em que implica utilizar async/await neste caso (no metodo main) no lugar de iniciar a Task de outra forma dentro do loop? Pergunto isto porque obtive estouro no pool de threads quando realizei o loop a partir de Task.Factory.StartNew, e este estouro parou de ocorrer quando mudei a abordagem para async/await.

```
    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tasks = new ConcurrentBag<Task>();

        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task1());
            tasks.Add(Task3());
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    }

    public async Task<int> Task1()
    {
        return await Task2();
    }

    public async Task<int> Task2()
    {
        return await Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(() => { return 3; });
    }

    public async Task<int> Task3()
    {
        return await Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(() => { return 3; });
    }
```

Comment: Você está interessado num exemplo teórico ou numa discussão de mundo real. Caso exemplo teórico, as respostas são (1) Não, esse código inicia *sincronamente* diversas tasks assíncronas e (2) Sim. A última questão parece mais caso de mundo real, cuja a resposta começa com um "depende".

Comment: @AndréLFSBacci, você está correto sobre o sincronamente, atualizei a pergunta porque era isto que queria dizer mesmo. Espero uma discussão de mundo real com embasamento teórico a respeito. A aplicação a ser desenvolvida é para atuar em um mundo real

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> var tasks = new ConcurrentBag<Task>();
> ```

`tasks`não precisa de ser uma `ConcurrentBag` pois não está a ser
acedida por várias threads.

> ```
> public async Task<int> Task2()
> {
>     return await Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(() => { return 3; });
> }
> ```

Neste método está a criar uma task com `StartNew` e pode remover
o `async` o `await` sem problema. Idem para `Task3`.

Tirando isto a sua técnica é de facto boa para executar várias 
tasks em paralelo. A ideia é de facto adiciona-las a uma lista
e esperar por todas ao mesmo tempo.

Também pode usar `WaitAny` para processar assim que uma `Task` tenha acabado.

**EDIT: Explicão sobre StartNew e `async` e `await`.**

Há vários aspectos a ter em consideração quando se usa o `StartNew` e resolvi editar a minha resposta.

---

Uma pergunta que você deve responder antes de utilizar o `StartNew` é:

**A operação que quero realizar é CPU bound ou I/O bound?**

Se a resposta for CPU bound, então deve ser o chamador a iniciar a operação numa task
se assim tiver interessado.

A intenção desta abordagem é que a API não tenha que disponibilizar sempre duas interfaces,
um sincrona e outra assincrona para um problema que engloba processamento.

---

Se a resposta for I/O bound o mais certo é que já exista uma API que disponibilize tasks,
se for esse o caso nunca precisará de chamar `StartNew`.

O método `StartNew` apenas agenda uma operação para ser realizada pelas threads to thread pool.
Isto quer dizer que esta mesma operação é relativamente rápida a executar.

---

Este mesmo método já retorna uma `Task`, o que quer dizer que é redundante usar `async` e `await`.

Básicamente quando escreve `await` está a dizer:

Executa este método assincronamente. 
Quando o método estiver completo resume a computação na thread chamadora.

---

Eu utilizei o Ildasm para inspecionar o código a nível do `IL` e como pode constantar o compilador gera código para reproduzir
as funcionalidades da keyword `await`. O código é o seguinte:

```
    public async Task<int> TaskD()
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => 3);
    }

    public Task<int> TaskE()
    {
        return Task.Run(() => 3);
    }
```

Pode ver a diferença do IL na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acrescento também que a não ser que precise de parametros extra do método `StartNew`, deve preferir `Task.Run`.

Comment: Existe algum problema neste caso para não se utilizar async/await?

Answer (score 1):

Essa é uma pergunta que provavelmente demandaria um livro para responder, mas tentar diminuir o escopo.

### `async`/`await` para composição de métodos

Você tem um sistema cheio de pequenas funcionalidades e trechos que *podem* ser rodados com algum nível de paralelismo. Nessa situação, em vez de encher o código de `Begin`/`End`, melhor usar `async`, `await` e `Task`por ser mais limpo e mais econômico. Esses comandos/classe fornecem toda uma infra-estrutura para encadeamento de comandos, e até mesmo a possibilidade de coreografia em nível de código ou de configuração.

O pulo do gato aí é lembrar que eles *não resolvem* problemas de paralelismo, apenas os formalizam. Uma vantagem indireta, como você mesmo percebeu, é que esse formalismo é mais econômico que (re)fazer todas essas funcionalidades na mão, fora que tendem a funcionar melhor que enfiar Task atrás de Task para processar sem se importar com os limites do sistema.

### `Thread` e `System.Collections.Concurrent` para controle

Pode ser que o sistema que está desenvolvendo precisa operar de forma multi thread, porém a parte que paralela seja relativamente pequena e/ou exija algum tipo de monitoração ou controle. Enfiar centenas de threads/tasks para execução posterior (eventual?) pode exaurir os recursos do sistema, como você mesmo viu, fora que dificulta medir o progresso sem alguma forma de coordenação ou estatística central.

Nessa situação pode ser bem mais preferível fazer classes especialistas que coordenam filas de itens a processar, e classes outras, "processadoras", que consomem dados dessas filas, alimentando outras filas ou empilhando resultados. Em vez do encadeamento de trechos por async/await, código fixo e rijo.

Essa *não é* uma linha de desenvolvimento mais elegante que a primeira, e geralmente é um tipo de *otimização prematura*. O processamento dos itens continua indeterminístico (por conta do paralelismo), mas a criação de instâncias de filas e processadores passa para o determinismo, o que pode ser necessário.

### *Crash and burn*, transacional coordenado ou transacional sem coordenação

Por fim, um *depende* muito importante diz respeito ao sentido de "em grande escala" mencionado acima.

Caso seja um tipo de processamento mais matemático, sem efeitos colaterais, *que possa ser simplesmente reexecutado em caso de falhas*, um sistema com `async`/`await` tende a ser preferível, pois a facilidade de composição é mais importante que a performance. Isso porque o paralelismo tende a aumentar a performance, mas não é mágico: a partir de certo ponto pode ficar pior que código sequencial, ou como percebeu, nem funcionar.

O mesmo para ambientes transacionais coordenados, quando o processamento gera efeitos colaterais, mas onde todas as APIs envolvidas são transacionais ou coordenáveis (TransactionScope). Nesses casos é preferível primeiro fazer o código que aguente rodar em paralelo do ponto de vista da transação que ficar otimizando cada leitura/escrita, mas eventualmente trechos em particular se mostrarão possíveis de paralelizar, e daí `async`/`await`/`Task` vão entrar em cena normalmente. A preocupação é mais com colisões/deadlocks *decorrentes* do paralelismo, não o paralelismo em si.

Mas existe a situação rara e triste, que você está fazendo algo transacional, com efeitos colaterais, mas não tem transação compartilhada/coordenada em todos os pontos. Comandos externos, web services, automação... Nessas horas o foco deve ser em fazer código paranoico, que lide bem com falhas, execuções  parciais e reexecuções sem duplicações, ou que ao menos consiga detectar essas situações em nível negocial. O tratamento de erro permeia o fluxo de código de tal maneira que ele fica na prática sequencial,  e o paralelismo vira uma preocupação secundária.

### Um alerta, talvez nada a ver

A propaganda o Entity Framework é ótima, e mesmo odiando essa API com todas as minhas forças, eu o utilizo em 100% dos meus projetos que envolvam banco dados. É uma boa API de *unit of work*.

O que a propaganda deixa de mencionar é que ela é uma API para *units* **pequenas** e *works* **não concorrentes**. EF com transações longas ou com muitos objetos é pedir para conhecer o inferno na terra. EF com concorrência, sozinho, beira a imprestabilidade.

Esse é um caso de um recurso compartilhado (dados no banco de dados) onde a API mais recomendada praticamente só oferece a solução tipo *crash and burn*, tudo ou nada.

---

Essa é uma resposta ainda genérica. Infelizmente é impossível entrar no detalhe sem conhecer o caso, a natureza da aplicação.

Importante notar que os estilos acima podem ser utilizados em pontos diversos do sistema. Na minha experiência o paralelismo tipo `async`/`await` é mais comum nos níveis mais baixos, quando operando no I/O, e nos níveis mais abstratos, negociais, esses comandos se tornam bem mais escassos, o paralelismo sendo substituído por objetos que cacheiam dados gerados assincronamente, e a utilização de eventos para notificação do progresso/conclusão de processamento assíncrono.

Comment: `Caso seja um tipo de processamento mais matemático ... um sistema com async/await tende a ser preferível, pois a facilidade de composição é mais importante que a performance. 
Isso porque o paralelismo tende a aumentar a performance`. 

Os processamentos matemáticos tem uma particularidade, eles tendem a depender de resultados de outras operações/funções.
É de notar que a keyword `await` **não porporciona qualquer parelelismo**, esta mesma keyword resolve apenas assincronismo.

A única forma de obter parelelismo usando tasks é usando `Task.WaitAll` ou `Task.WaitAny`. Ou as variantes com When.

Comment: `Enfiar centenas de threads/tasks para execução posterior (eventual?) pode exaurir os recursos do sistema`. Threads sim, tasks nem por isso. Quando se usam tasks estão a utilizar-se as threads do threadpool que tenta fazer o melhor trabalho possivel para tentar manter o número de threads tão baixo quanto possivel e tão alto quanto o número de cores disponivel. Muito simplisticamente as taks podem ser vistas apenas como um ponteiro para uma função que é necessário executar.