# Metodo Async com Await no return dele

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> NomeMetodo([FromUri] Filtro filtro)
{
    return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>Ok(_aplicacao.RetornarDados(filtro)));
}
```

Gostaria de saber porque o método acima faz sentido, já que ele é `async` mas estou esperando o retorno dele no `await`, o que pra mim fica parecido com um método normal sincrono.
Não manjo muito de asyncs, poderiam me explicar?

Comment: Pode ver [na minha resposta a esta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123707/melhores-pr%C3%A1ticas-ao-trabalhar-com-multithread/123716#123716) onde eu discuto exatamente isto. Nomeadamente desde `Este mesmo método já retorna uma Task, o que quer dizer que é redundante usar async e await`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesse caso realmente não faz sentido o uso de **async/await**.
O assincronismo é uma maneira de informar uma **Thread** que ao ocorrer uma operação **await** essa **Thread** não precisa ficar esperando pelo resultado do **await** para processar outras informações. Isso significa que aquela **Thread** que ficaria em tempo ocioso durante uma certa operação nesse caso estará livre para processar outras informações enquanto a operação **await** não for finalizada.

Só que operações com assincronismo só fazem sentido quando você está trabalhando com recursos de terceiros, onde o processamento não será efetuado pelo mesmo recurso que serve para rodar o seu código. Um exemplo bem simples de se perceber isso é quando consumimos bibliotecas de terceiros através do protocolo **HTTP**. Aqui está um exemplo (simplificado) retirado da própria [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh191443.aspx):

```
async Task<int> AccessTheWebAsync()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    DoIndependentWork();

    string urlContents = await client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");

    return urlContents.Length;
}
```

Note que ao efetuarmos uma chamada ao método **GetStringAsync** aqui estamos usando a palavra reserva **await**, informando que essa é uma operação assíncrona. Nesse contexto faz sentido o uso do assincronismo, nós estamos fazendo uma chamada para um serviço externo, onde o processamento não é efetuado pelos mesmos recursos que gerenciam o nosso código, onde o tempo de resolução do método pode ser de vários minutos por causa de gargalos que o site está enfrentando ou até mesmo pode ocorrer algum problema. Se o processamento está sendo feito por outro recurso que não é o meu, porque eu deveria travar os recursos de uma **Thread**, sendo que os meus recursos poderiam estar livres para resolver outros problemas?

### Um exemplo mais humano para o entendimento:

Nós temos um cozinheiro que está preparando um omelete. O cozinheiro tem que efetuar várias tarefas para conseguir preparar o omelete, como quebrar os ovos, mexer os ovos, colocar sal dentro dos ovos mexidos e por fim, colocar os ovos em uma frigideira. Só que o nosso cozinheiro decidiu que iria colocar queijo derretido encima do omelete e usaria de um microondas para isso. Veja que todas as ações de quebrar o ovo, mexer os ovos e colocar sal dentro dos ovos precisa que o cozinheiro use de seus recursos **(suas mãos)** para efetuar essas ações, só que esquentar o queijo é uma tarefa do microondas, que só precisa receber o queijo **(parâmetros)**. Obviamente que o cozinheiro precisa esperar pelo queijo derretido para colocar ele encima dos ovos e se servir, mas ele precisa ficar parado na frente do microondas esperando o queijo ser derretido? Enquanto isso, ele poderia começar o preparo de outros pratos, enquanto o queijo está sendo derretido.

### Porque o exemplo colocado na pergunta não faz sentido?

No código postado no exemplo não existe qualquer ação que é efetuada por terceiros e que demande de assincronismo. O assincronismo muito provavelmente deveria estar no método **RetornarDados**, só que ele pelo jeito não possui um retorno assincrono. Isso poderia ser corrigido da seguinte maneira:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> NomeMetodo([FromUri] Filtro filtro)
{
    var dados = await _aplicacao.RetornarDadosAsync(filtro);
    return Ok(dados);
}
```

Note que o sufixo de **Async** é uma boa prática para informar que o método possui um retorno assincrono, seguindo um ótimo princípio da programação: Príncipio da menor surpresa.

Creio que esse método deve estar efetuando uma operação em um banco de dados. Note que um recurso de terceiros pode ser até mesmo um recurso da sua própria máquina. Operações de **I/O** são exemplos de um uso de assincronismo onde o recurso de terceiro é efetuado pela sua própria máquina.

Comment: A resposta parece estar correta, mas fala muito em *thread*, o que nem é garantido que exista em um assincronismo do C#. Talvez queira dizer tarefa.

Comment: Sim, está correto. Eu fui escrevendo e me equivoquei nos termos.